# Applying multiple stylesheets to chosen.js dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen.js to implement jQuery dropdowns... https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen

If I want multiple dropdowns styled differently is there a way to apply a different stylesheet to each dropdown? There is a clue here but I haven't figured it out yet.. https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/935

Answer (score 0):

If stof's answer doesn't work (from the link provided), I guess you can still wrap it in a div with a custom class or ID, can't you ?

```
<div class="myCustomStyledChosen">
    <select...
</div>
```

and then in your stylesheet

```
.myCustomStyledChosen
{
    yourstyles..
}
```